# How to Update Images and Text in Firebase and Retrieve Them In RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I followed a Tutorial and was Successfully able to Load the data in Firebase and also retrieve it back in RecyclerView and also Learned How to Delete data but now I'm Stuck that how to update this data in the Firebase and show it in RecyclerView.I have used Picasso for the Images.

This is my Gallery.java file

```
public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST= 1;

private Button mButtonChooseImage;
private Button mButtonUpload;
private TextView mTextViewShowGallery;
private EditText mEditTextFileName,mEditTextDesc;
private ImageView mImageView;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

private Uri mImageUri;

private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

private StorageTask mUploadTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

    mButtonChooseImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    mButtonUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    mTextViewShowGallery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    mEditTextFileName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    mEditTextDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           openFileChooser();
        }
    });

    mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress())
            {
                Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, "Upload In Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                uploadFile();
            }
        }
    });

    mTextViewShowGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            openImagesActivity();
        }
    });
}


private void openFileChooser ()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        mImageUri = data.getData();

        Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
    }
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri)
{
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}


private void uploadFile()
{
    if (mImageUri != null)
    {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        },500);

                        Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                mEditTextDesc.getText().toString().trim(),taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(uploadImage);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(Gallery.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
                    }
                });

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void openImagesActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this,ImagesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

This below one is the ImagesActivity which is for the recyclerview, here the delete operation works, as I mentioned and I have used the AlertDialog to open and update the details I tried to Mimic some things from gallery.java but was not able to figure out how they should be Arranged.

```
public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST= 1;
private StorageTask mUploadTask;

private Uri mImageUri;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;

private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private ValueEventListener mDBListener;

private List<UploadImage> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mProgressCircle= findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();


    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this,mUploads);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mUploads.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                UploadImage uploadImage = postSnapshot.getValue(UploadImage.class);
                uploadImage.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(uploadImage);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });


}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri)
{
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Normal Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@Override
public void onUpdateClick(int position) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText TextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    final EditText TextDesc = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    final ImageView ImageView = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    final Button chooseFile = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    final Button UpdateDetails = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Update Details");
    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();


    chooseFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            openFileChooser();

        }
    });


    UpdateDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress())
            {
                Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Upload In Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                if (mImageUri != null)
                {
                    StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

                    mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                                    Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage(TextName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                            TextDesc.getText().toString().trim(),taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                                    String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                                    mDatabaseRef.setValue(uploadImage);
                                    mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(uploadImage);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "No File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            b.dismiss();

        }

    });



    UploadImage selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();
  //  Toast.makeText(this, "Update Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void openFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}


@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {

    UploadImage selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

            mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
}
```

}

This below one is for set and get methods named as UploadImage.java

```
public class UploadImage {

private String mName;
private String mDesc;
private String mImageUrl;
private String mKey;


public UploadImage()
{
    //Empty Constructor Needed
}

public UploadImage(String name, String desc, String imageUrl)
{
    if (name.trim().equals(""))
    {
        name = "No Name";
        desc = "No Description";
    }
    mName = name;
    mDesc = desc;
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return mDesc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    mDesc=desc;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl=imageUrl;
}

@Exclude
public String getKey(){
    return mKey;
}

@Exclude
public void setKey(String key){
    mKey = key;
}
```

}

The following one for the Adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<UploadImage> mUploads;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<UploadImage> uploads){

        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item,parent,false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        UploadImage uploadImageCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadImageCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadImageCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_black_24dp)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener{

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mListener != null)
            {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){

                    //To Handle Normal Item Clicks
                    mListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
            MenuItem Update = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Update");
            MenuItem Delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");

            Update.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            Delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            if (mListener != null)
            {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){

                    //To Check Which Menu Item Was Clicked
                    switch (item.getItemId())
                    {
                        case 1:
                            mListener.onUpdateClick(position);
                            return true;
                        case 2:
                            mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{

        void onItemClick(int position);
        void onUpdateClick(int position);
        void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){

        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Any Solution for this how can I update it.

Comment: did you mean to use a onProgressListener where you used a onPausedListener?

Comment: No sir I want to update the Image and text which are there in my database, when i longpress on recycler view A flowting menu, appears and it has two options update and delete, the delete works and when i click on update A alertDialog will appear with the same ui has I have used for uploading the image and text to the data base i wanted to know how can i update details , I tried some things by copying certain data from gallery.java in the this activity(ImagesActivity), but No images loads and nothing happens I know i have  missing some things but wat that i dont know

Answer (score 0):

There is no update method in firebase storage, So for a workaround:

- get the name the file you want to delete
- delete the file you want to update
- upload the new file
- rename file with the previous file name